# Default namespace in website

Tags: web, namespaces, default

I just found out that I can get/set a default namespace in my web app by going to project > Properties > Application.  Apparently this only applies to VB.Net, and not C#.Net, for some reason.

How do I find out what the default namespace is for the website I just created?  The project properties look completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default namespace for your C# web app is just the name of your project.
It's added to the code for you automatically. Also the file structure within your project will determine what the default namespace for that file. If you have a Views folder in your app you would get `namespace SampleNamespace.Views` and it is recommended through a number of style enforcing tools that you mirror the file structure in your namespaces.

Here's an example from microsoft.

```
namespace SampleNamespace 
{
    class SampleClass{}
    interface SampleInterface{}
    struct SampleStruct{}
    enum SampleEnum{a,b}
    delegate void SampleDelegate(int i);
    namespace SampleNamespace.Nested
    {
       class SampleClass2{}
    }
}
```

Comment: What if it's vb.net instead of C#.Net?

Comment: It's really the same concept in VB, but it's a little more transparent to the developer.

Here is a little link to a site that goes over it pretty well.
http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/net/nettip40.asp